# ggplot2 show layered points correctly in legend with several groupings

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I wish to indicate certain points in my plot both by color and by circling them (for black and white viewing). I am already using the shape parameter for a separate grouping, but can do this by using two `geom_point` layers. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to get the legend to correspond to my points. Here is a minimal example to show what I mean:

```
x <- data.frame(names = rep(letters[1:24],2), 
            grouping1 = factor(rep(c("Treatment", "Control"), each = 24)),
            grouping2 = factor(rep(rep(c("Matched","Unmatched"), each = 12), 2)), 
            values1 = runif(48, 60, 120), values2 = runif(48, 11, 25))


ggplot(data = x, aes(x = values1, y = values2, group = names)) +
     geom_point(aes(shape = grouping1, color = grouping2)) +
     geom_line(alpha = 0.2) +
     geom_point(data = x[x$grouping1 == 1 & x$grouping2 == 1,], aes(values1, values2), 
                shape = 21, size = 3, show.legend = TRUE)
```

If I include `show.legend = TRUE` as above this circles everything in the legend. I would like only the red points (as in the graph) to be circled by a border in the legend as well. Thankful for any help.[image]

Comment: So far I can almost get there by using `fill` along with `color`, but the circles end up the same color as the points.  Would that be sufficient, given that this is going to be in black and white?  What colors are you  planning to use for the points for printing?  May try `scale_color_grey`.

Comment: That might be ok, perhaps you could show how as an answer? I would like to keep the coloring since the majority of people will just read the pdf-file, so using `scale_color_grey` is not an option (to my understanding).

Answer (score 1):

If you combine your two groups, it's simpler to get them all in the legend

```
x$bothgroups <- paste(x$grouping1, x$grouping2)
```

Then use shapes 21 - 25, which have color and fill characteristics.  That way, you can set color to use black for the points you want circled, creating a dark outline, and use the same color as fill for points you don't want circled, so they show up as solid color points without outlines.

```
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = values1, y = values2, group = names)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = bothgroups, color = bothgroups, fill = bothgroups,
                 stroke = 1.5)) + #make border thicker so it is visible
  geom_line(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24, 21, 21)) + #circle triangle circle circle
  #fill sets color in center of points
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "green", "tomato", "green")) +
  #color sets outline color - match to fill for points you don't want circled
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "green", "black", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I'm not so happy with how it looks because the groupings are string variables (I updated my example code to reflect this).  I would prefer to keep the two grouping variables separate in the legend if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close to what you want if you use fillable points.  That way you can you can map both `fill` and `color` scales to `grouping2`.  This makes it so only the one legend is affected by the additional `geom_point` layer.  You can then modify the legend to remove the circle for the second group using `override.aes` in `guide_legend`.

I used `override.aes` to keep a filled point `shape` legend, as well, as using fillable points changes what the shape legend looks like by default.

Here's one option, where the surrounding circle is the same color as the points:

```
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = values1, y = values2, group = names)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = grouping1, fill = grouping2, colour = grouping2)) +
    geom_line(alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_point(data = x[x$grouping1 == 1 & x$grouping2 == 1,], 
               aes(values1, values2, color = grouping2),
               shape = 1, size = 3 ) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24) ) + # fillable shapes
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("#F8766D", NA),
                                                   shape = 21) ),
           shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black") ) )
```

[image]

A subtly different option, keeping the circle around the points black.  However, it also puts a black outline on the filled points (i.e., makes the "stroke" color black).  The stroke color of the other group is kept the same as the fill color.

```
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = values1, y = values2, group = names)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = grouping1, fill = grouping2, colour = grouping2)) +
    geom_line(alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_point(data = x[x$grouping1 == 1 & x$grouping2 == 1,], 
               aes(values1, values2, color = grouping2),
               shape = 21, size = 3 ) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24) ) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#00BFC4") ) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("black", NA),
                                                   shape = 21) ),
           shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black") ) )
```

[image]